# Laravel custom column in select statement

Tags: laravel

I have this fields '*questions_count*' and '*case_study_count*' which are got as a result of *withCount* relation.
Now, I wanted to sum these values in a select statement.

```
postCount = questions_count + case_study_count
```

This is my code

```
public function getTopTags() {
    return $this->tag
                ->select('id','title')
                ->withCount(['questions' => function($qry) {
                    if(\Auth::user()->role->role_code == config('constants.ROLES.USER.STUDENT')) {
                            $qry->whereIn('category_id', config('constants.STUDENT_VIEW_CATEGORIES'));
                        }   else {
                            $qry->whereNotIn('category_id', config('constants.STUDENT_ADD_CATEGORIES'));
                        }
                    $qry->where('is_active', 'Y');
                }])
                ->withCount(['case_study' => function($qry) {
                    if(\Auth::user()->role->role_code == config('constants.ROLES.USER.STUDENT')) {
                            $qry->whereIn('category_id', config('constants.STUDENT_VIEW_CATEGORIES'));
                        }   else {
                            $qry->whereNotIn('category_id', config('constants.STUDENT_ADD_CATEGORIES'));
                        }
                    $qry->where('is_active', 'Y');
                }])
                // ->select('(questions_count + case_study_count) as postCount')
                //->selectRaw('questions_count + case_study_count')

                ->orderByRaw('(questions_count + case_study_count) desc')
                ->where('is_active', 'Y')
                ->get();
}
```

So, Basically after calling this function, it should return

1. id
2. title
3. postCount

Comment: Just add them in your select-list? `select('id', 'title', \DB::raw('questions_count + case_study_count AS post_count'))`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to remove the "orderbyraw" and in the front end create a column with the sum you want.

Comment: how to create a column with the sum? orderBy is working good now

Comment: when you are in the front end you will do a foreach to print out your table and you will have one more column with 
    {{$YOU_CONTROLLER->questions + $YOU_CONTROLLER->case_study}}

Comment: So, no more workarounds for this? I wonder why orderBy works fine, but couldn't use this in select statement

Comment: orderByRaw uses a column not it's value so this will not work and you don't need to complicate things take the values and make a sum in front end.